# it's high time or time

Tags: verbs, past-tense, usage

Do we always use past simple after "it's about time"?
*It's about time we worked* but *it was about time we had worked* or *just worked* and only past simple is acceptable after "it's time"?

Comment: It *was* about time we had worked or worked the full day.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if one is saying it in the present, then present tense is also an option: "It's about time we work" or "It's about time we get to work," though past simple is more common. And I think that if the whole narrative is moved into the past, you would still use simple past with the "about time" idiom: "The hour had come. It was about time we got to work." In fact, though it's a bit unlikely to happen, I could imagine it being used in a future-tense context: "Tomorrow it will be high time we got to work."

Comment: I found 'When we return from our holiday it will be {high) time we changed the code' quoted as an example in _Modality in English: Theory and Description (Topics in English linguistics, 58)_ by Pierre Busuttil, Johan van der Auwera, Raphael Salkie.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: There’s also *It’s about time **for** S **to** V*, as in *It’s about time for us to work* and *It’s about time for the baby to be put to bed*.